High voltage, low current connectors
I am currently looking for a basic wire connector (banana plug like or else) that are rated for 8 kV DC but with a very low current (20 uA).
My question, would a regular 15 A rated connector be considered safe? Or would that be against regulations?

I believe there are 10 kV rated banana plugs/jacks made by Cal Test, though a better solution would use high-voltage coaxial connectors with a grounded shield to limit the danger of an insulation nick leading to arcing. 20 μA is very low current, so you definitely need a connector with self-wiping contacts (most HV ones I know of have those to a greater or lesser extent, though).

@Hearth Do you think the self-wiping is necessary with 10kV? I think it's a requirement of low current '&' low voltage not '|'.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany It might be fine without it, but it is the current that breaks through oxides, not the voltage alone. It doesn't take much charge, so it can be a very brief inrush into parasitic capacitances, but on a physical level I'm pretty sure it is current that matters here.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I have never actually tried, but keeping 10kV from piercing a thin oxide layer is problematic. 20uA @ 10kV is 0.2W, and that's if there was a theoretical 20uA limit. When parasitic capacitances discharge, there won't be any such limit unless highly resistive cable is used, so the initial zap will be hard and will make it through, and should have plenty of energy to develop into an arc that will blow oxide off. Of course I could be wrong, but that's how I see this happening.

I'd say wiping is, and isn't, important. If the conductors ever come loose, their capacitances charges up until the gap sparks -- for a loose, dirty, but otherwise mated connector, 100s of V tops. The spark may generate a lot of noise and aggressively accelerate contact wear, or it blows out the contamination, and maybe even microwelds the contacts together. I would expect clean plated contacts with good wiping is most desirable to avoid this process entirely.

Gas laser power connectors may be an option.  He-Ne (2-12kV) and CO2 (10-30kV) are the ones that are high voltage.  I have met polarised paired connectors and single connectors.  I think Alden is one of the connector types.

You are going to have to worry about creepage and clearance to prevent arcing as well as adaquate insulation (especially for connectors that have more than one conductor). The connector needs to be rated for high voltage.
Make sure they are rated for the voltage that you are using.

Got it, so even if the amperage is low. I should still look for a 10kV connector for my case for example.

Yep, its really arcing that will be the problem

You can find connectors from Pasternak etc. that are rated for 10kV/20kV.
They are coaxial so they look roughly similar to RF connectors such as BNC and type N but with longer/more insulation.
Eg. this one.

For even higher low-current voltages there are connectors that are used in X-ray power supplies that look fairly similar in overall appearance but are good for 50~100kV+. Some of them appear to be proprietary such as this one.


@Sphero. Depending on the source, SHV and MHV are rated for 5 kV. OP is asking for 8 kV. A coax connector may be pushing it. You linked to the PE45839 (rated10 kV). Is that connector a special version of the SHV? Or of the MHV? Or is it completely different?

@DavideAndrea I don't know- I've not had need of these connectors to do a detailed comparison. I'm super glad you're doing such comparisons though.

Since I wrote you, I did some research, and it appears that these connectors are upgraded versions of the HMV. I thank you for making me aware of these connectors.

If you knew exactly what you are doing, you wouldn't have to ask the question. On the other hand, everyone had to learn somehow. Asking such question is one of the best ways to learn!
You shall always account for both amperage and voltage expected for your application in worst-case scenario. And include safety margins. No matter it is connection, conduction or switching. If you can, try to estimate switching  properties, some sources may have voltage or current spike when turned on or off.

Amperage dictates heating of the device through Joule's heat (P=RI^2).
Voltage dictates the insulation, because every insulator has its own breakup voltage (V/m). When the voltage is too high or the insulation stack between wires too thin, the arc will form.

For switching you have to account for both voltage and amperage because of switch on and switch off arcing. There are nice videos on the internets of arcs when powerlines swithces off or on.
Look up for connectors rated above your envelope, say 10 - 15kV at least, the current is low enough to care - all connectors will be rated way above.
